# Cannot create property key on string React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm making a chat app using React and keep getting an error with my code that states:

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'key' on string 'room1'

I'm using firebase as my database and have two objects. I'm using room1 and room2 and I got an error going through the two objects.

I've been at this for days and I can't get it. Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class RoomList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
         this.state = {
     rooms: [],
            newRoomName: ''
         };
         this.roomsRef = this.props.firebase.database().ref("rooms");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.roomsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
         const room = snapshot.val();
         room.key = snapshot.key;
         this.setState({ rooms: this.state.rooms.concat( room ) })
      });
    }

    createRoom(newRoomName) {
        this.roomsRef.push({
            name: newRoomName 
        });
        this.setState({ newRoomName: '' });
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ newRoomName: e.target.value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.createRoom(this.state.newRoomName);
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <section className="room-list">
        <h3>Rooms</h3>
                {this.state.rooms.map( room => 
                     <li key={room.key} >
                        {room.name}
                     </li>
                )}
                <form id="create-room" onSubmit={ (e) => this.handleSubmit(e) }>
                    <input type="text" value={ this.state.newRoomName } onChange={ (e) => this.handleChange(e) }/>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
          </section>
      );
    }
}

export default RoomList;
```

The error is caught where `room.key = snapshot.key`

and heres my App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import RoomList from './components/RoomList';

// Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyD4geqW7VZ7e7trfIASUQaWaJA9pmGDzUE",
    authDomain: "bloc-chat-81cb7.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://bloc-chat-81cb7.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "bloc-chat-81cb7",
    storageBucket: "bloc-chat-81cb7.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "229890444186"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rooms: [],
      newRoomName: ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1 className="App-title">Bloc Chat</h1>
        <main>
           <RoomList firebase={firebase} />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: It looks like the value of `room` is a string. Your cannot create properties on primitive values, although this usually doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Would it be best to make it an object then?

Comment: You are manipulating on a constant.. i.e., const room. Can we update a const variable after assigning it? I think we can't.

Comment: @G_S: You cannot assign a new value to a `const`, but you can mutate mutable values, such as arrays or objects.  The (im)mutability of the binding is independent of the one of the value.

Comment: @FelixKling, Yes. got it.. Thanks for correcting me